# How to change the row number in range as variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change range row number as a variable,& get it defined in another sheet,how do I do that ? (in following example "D2:D1999",I want to specify "2" in another sheet and include in vb code.)

```
Sub Del()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim x As Long


    With Sheets("RCSamples")

        Set rng = .Range("D2:D1999")


        rng.EntireRow.Delete

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please mark below as the answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 0):

```
With Sheets("RCSamples")

    Set rng = .Range("D" & Sheets("OtherSheet").range("WheretheNumberis") & ":D1999")


    rng.EntireRow.Delete

End With
```